# keep losing names from numbers on my contacts list in my HTC desire s

Tags: contacts, htc-desire-s

I keep losing names from numbers saved to SIM in my contacts list randomly on my new HTC desire S. If I reboot my phone, they come back, only to disappear again randomly! Only some of my contact's names disappear and all my contact's numbers are saved to SIM in the same way....!? What do you reckon?